# deps.json file is missing when trying to build and run net core app on docker, but works fine on my local

Tags: .net, docker

So I have a root folder with a sln file, and then 4 folders with 4 csproj inside the src folder, and this is my dockerfile:

```
# Build Stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the entire project and restore dependencies
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore --output ./publish

# Publish Stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 as runtime
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the published output from the build stage
COPY --from=build /app/publish .

# Expose the port the application will listen on
EXPOSE 5000

# Define the entry point for your application
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApi.dll"]
```

I am missing a deps.json file inside my app folder when I look inside my docker container and it won't run and crashes, even after adding it, the application doesn't start. I had a publish in there, but I removed it because it wasn't working. What am I doing wrong? The dotnet restore works fine.

Moreover, I ran dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore --output ./publish on the root directory on Windows, and ran dotnet MyApi.dll inside of publish and it works and it doesn't say I am missing something. I also ran it by navigating to the api directory and running dotnet run, so there's something inside the docker config that's not right, but I am not getting any error until the last command runs and it says I am missing a file, and as I've said even if I add the file, it doesn't run correctly.

I looked at the folders to compare both and it seems to be roughly the same, it's just missing a file it seems.

Could it be related to dotnet restore, I used dotnet/core/sdk:7.0 and fixed the issue I had with the Nuget private repository, but after switching to sdk:2.2 I got a different error and I fixed it by modifying the nuget.config file and passing in the secret token, so I don't understand and as I've said I am not getting any error as I did before in the earlier stage, it's only at the very end.

Comment: Just wanna make sure that you realize that .NET Core 2.2 has been EOL for almost 4 years now.